# How to update JUnit5 jupiter.api_5.3.1 to jupiter.api_5.4.2?

Tags: eclipse, testing, junit5

i want to know that if "MethodOrderer" class is available in JUnit5 Library FOR ECLIPSE or not, because i am unable to find it.
If not, how can i shift jupiter.api_5.3.1 to jupiter.api_5.4.2 in eclipse JUnit5 library?

Will be thankful to see your reply.

I downloaded JUnit5 jar file from "https://search.maven.org/artifact/name.remal.tools.test/junit5/1.26.97/jar" and this jar does have "MethodOrderer" class but when i add this to project dependency and run the testclass, eclipse shows up this error "No tests found with test runner 'JUnit5'."

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class JunitCalculatorV4 {
    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before All");
    }
    @AfterAll
    static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("After All");
    }
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void addTest() {
        System.out.println("Add test");
    }
    @Test
    @Order(2)
    void divideTest() {
        System.out.println("Divide Test");
    }

}
```

Actually this annotation `@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)`  is from `jupiter.api_5.4.2` which i added as an external jar, and that might be causing conflict with the existing JUnit5 library.

**My problem would be solved if the JUnit5 library is updated as a whole, or atleast the jarfile inside the library is updated.**

*Project > Properties: Java Build Path*, tab *Libraries*:

[image]

Comment: [Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11) includes JUnit 5.4](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.11/jdt.php#junit-5.4). But it depends on how JUnit is added to your Java Build Path (e.g. via Maven or Gradle dependencies, via using the included JUnit library or via adding the JARs manually). If upgrading Eclipse does not fix your issue, show your _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_.

Comment: JUnit5 is added via Library, but the Library does not have updated jupiter.api jar file.
have a look at this image: https://i.ibb.co/phGk6xK/Untitled.png
I want the jar in referenced libraries to be moved to JUnit5 library, ***just like the arrow is placed in the picture.***

Comment: Obviously you have an outdated Eclipse version. [Please upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).

Comment: I'll try it and respond here, thanks for responding :)

Comment: I have updated eclipse but still not working, cant i just update the JUnit5 library anyway?

Comment: Sure, you can add any JUnit version on the Java Build Path. There a couple of ways to do this. Show your _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_ and tell which Eclipse version do you have (_Help > About_).

Comment: @howlger ! How can i use `@Order` annotation in eclipse, kindly guide me to that one.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_ with expanded tree nodes to show the JARs you currently have.

Comment: @howlger sorry Sir but my repute on stack is not enough that i could post the image directly here.
Here is imageUrl: https://i.ibb.co/xqPhnMh/buildpath-eclipse.png

Comment: Obviously, you're still on Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) instead of Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11) (see JAR file names containing `..._5.3.1.v20181005-...` instead of `..._5.4.0.v20190212-...`). Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).

Comment: @howlger Thanks Sir, the issue is fixed now. The support was not available in **Eclipse 2018-03** i update eclipse to **2019-03** and now latest JUnit5 jupiter packages are automatically added. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) with JUnit 5.3.1 instead of [Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11) with JUnit 5.4.0](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.11/jdt.php#junit-5.4)** (the screenshot shows JAR file names containing `_5.3.1.v20181005-` instead of `_5.4.0.v20190212-`).

Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).